# "You are not authorized to perform this operation"

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

I am admin for our AWS environment, and wanted to use PowerShell, but I get these errors whenever I try to do anything

> Get-EC2Region : You are not authorized to perform this operation.

or

> Get-CSDomain : User: arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/Jane.Doe is not  authorized to perform: cloudsearch:DescribeDomains on resource: arn:aws:cloudsearch:eu-west-1:123456789012:domain/*

In my personal AWS account, everything works fine. We had a look at our policies, and us four admins can all do everything using the webconsole.
I have regenerated my access keys just in case that might be it, but there was no change.

So I guess my questions is:Do we need to implement some CLI specific policies to allow access via PowerShell?

Comment: You need to make sure the user you are using the correct AWS user credentials and the correct IAM policy to allow the `cloudsearch:DescribeDomains` operation.

Can you double check and add that policy to your question?

Comment: There are now PowerShell specific policies. Its a IAM permission issue for sure.

Comment: There are *no* ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the user you are using the correct AWS user credentials and the correct IAM policy to allow the given user to do the operation.

There are no CLI specific policies to PowerShell. The user simply has not been granted those permissions.

A good test would be to grant the user `ec2:*` and `cloudsearch:*` and confirm. then you can tighten down the permissions, having confirmed that the user can be successfully given a more permissive set of permissions.

Comment: I have these admin rights:  

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}`

I thought that should give me full access...

Comment: Yes - root access I believe.  And you still get permission errors? If so, then you need to double check your credentials/identity.

Comment: Yes, I still get that error. I have two AWS accounts, and the other one works fine. I created new access keys, just in case, but still get the error. I am going to try creating a new admin user and see how it goes...

Comment: I have crated a new admin user, and this one works fine...  

This makes me think that maybe my account wasn't enabled for programmatic access, despite having access keys. So I will have to see if I can enable that on my account.

Comment: I do not believe there is a setting for enabling programmatic access. Any resource can be accessed by any user with correct permissions/credentials.